# how to get the backend_status using qiskit?

Tags: qiskit

I was preparing for the exam and I was confused about how to get job and backend status using qiskit, do we use `Job_monitor` for both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [`Job_monitor`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.tools.job_monitor.html) to get the status of a job (`IBMQJob` instance)

To get the status of an IBMQ backend, we use [`IBMQBackend.status()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.IBMQBackend.status.html) which returns a [`BackendStatus`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.models.BackendStatus.html) instance:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ

if IBMQ.active_account() is None:
    IBMQ.load_account()

provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub = 'ibm-q')
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_quito')

print('Status:')
print('  Operational: ', backend.status().operational)
print('  Pending jobs:', backend.status().pending_jobs)
print('  Status message:', backend.status().status_msg)
```

Result of this code snippet should be some thing like:

```
Status:
  Operational:  True
  Pending jobs: 108
  Status message: active
```